# Resolve Invalid Scope Error Identity Server 6

Tags: razor-pages, duende-identity-server

I am new to Identity server, recently set it up for a project, but I keep getting the following error

> Sorry, there was an error : invalid_scope Invalid scope

**These are the components that comprise the application.**

Web Client -> ASPNETCORE Razor Pages application (Port: 7091)

Ocelot -> API Gateway

Identity Server 6 (Port: 5001)

StripeDotNet -> API

Basket -> API

**My configurations/code are as follows:**

*Identity Server*

```
  public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
               // new IdentityResources.Email(),
            };
        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new List<ApiScope>
            {
                new ApiScope("stripedotnetapi", "StripeDotNet API")
            };
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            {            
                // interactive ASP.NET Core MVC client
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "razorweb",
                    ClientName = "Razor Web",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                
                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7091/signin-oidc" },

                    //FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:7091/signout-callback-oidc",

                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7091/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                       // IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "stripedotnetapi"
                    }
                }
            };
    }
```

*Identity Server: Hosting Extensions*

```
 builder.Services
                .AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                    // see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/resources/
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

*StripeDotNet API*

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddSecurityServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("scope", "stripedotnetapi");
                });
            });

            return services;
        }
```

*StripeDotNet API: Controller Code*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize("ApiScope")]
    public class CheckoutController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly ICheckoutService _checkoutService;

        public CheckoutController(ICheckoutService checkoutService)
        {
            _checkoutService = Guard.Against.Null(checkoutService, nameof(checkoutService));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCheckoutSession([FromBody] CreateCheckoutSessionRequest req)
        {
            var response = await _checkoutService.CreateCheckoutSessionAsync(req.TenantId, req.PriceId,
                req.SuccessUrl, req.CancelUrl);

            return Ok(response);
        }

        [HttpGet("{sessionId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCheckoutSession(string sessionId)
        {
            var response = await _checkoutService.GetCheckoutSessionAsync(sessionId);

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

*Ocelot API Gateway*

```
var authenticationProviderKey = "IdentityApiKey";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(authenticationProviderKey, x =>
    {
        x.Authority = "https://localhost:5001"; // IDENTITY SERVER URL
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
```

*Ocelot API Gateway: Configuration file*

```
{
  "UpStreamPathTemplate": "/api/Checkout",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 7056
    }
  ],
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Checkout",
  "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "IdentityApiKey",
    "AllowedScopes": []
  }
},
{
  "UpStreamPathTemplate": "/api/Checkout/{sessionId}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 7056
    }
  ],
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Checkout/{sessionId}",
  "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "IdentityApiKey",
    "AllowedScopes": []
  }
},
```

*Web Client*

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSecurityServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

        options.ClientId = "razorweb";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        //options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("stripedotnetapi");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    });

    return services;
}
```

My discovery endpoint shows these items as valid scopes

```
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "stripedotnetapi",
    "offline_access"
  ],
```

The supported scopes appear to be setup correctly for the web client, but I keep getting an invalid scope error. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I didnt pay close enough attention to the docs. Offline Access was not granted to the client.

```
AllowOfflineAccess = true,
```